# Finding a homotopy between twice-punctured n-sphere and (n-1)-sphere

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Say I removed two points, say $(0, 0, \ldots, \pm 1)$ from the $n$-sphere, I want to show this is homotopy equivalent to the (n-1)-sphere.
I thought to construct a deformation retract:
$$
F(a_1, \ldots, a_n, t) = (b_1)^2 + \ldots (b_{n-1})^2 + (1-t)(b_n)^2 
$$
But, I'm unsure how to pick the values of these $b_i$'s. Since I have that the squares of both the $a_i$'s and the $b_i$'s have to sum to $1$, I could do some algebraic manipulation with that but it doesn't take me far.

Comment: When you remove a point from $S^n$, you will get $\mathbb R^n$, now what will you get if you remove a point from $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: Oh wait. Isn't $\mathbb{R}^n-\{0\}$ homeomorphic to $S^n$? That makes sense. My question, though: that's allowed? Say I have a finitely punctured, say $k$ times, space $X$. Can I just start with an unpunctured object, puncture it once, find what that is homotopic to, then puncture that once, then find what that's homotopic it, and puncture that once and so on? It certainly feels illegal, like one of those things that feels illegal but might not be, like driving barefoot

Comment: This can be shown, if you like, by induction.

Answer (score 3):

I'll represent element of $S^n$ $\mathbf a=(a_1,\cdots,a_n,a_{n+1})$ as $(\cos\theta\mathbf a_0,\sin\theta)$, while $\mathbf a_0$ is element of $S^{n-1}$(and, surely $-\frac\pi2\le\theta\le\frac\pi2$). It is reasonable because $1=\|\mathbf a\|^2=\|\cos\theta\mathbf a_0\|^2+\sin^2\theta=\cos^2\theta\|\mathbf a_0\|^2+\sin^2\theta$, so $\mathbf a_0\in S^{n-1}$.

And $\mathbf a_0$ is well-defined while $\mathbf a\ne(0,\cdots,0,\pm1)$, which is $\theta\ne\pm\frac\pi2$. So, I'll remove two point like you: $\mathbf n=(0,\cdots,0,1),\mathbf s=(0,\cdots,0,-1)$ is removed.

Then, the deformation retraction from $S^n-\{\mathbf n,\mathbf s\}$ to $S^{n-1}$(strictly, $S^{n-1}\times\{0\}$) is performed like this...

$$F(\mathbf a,t)=(\cos{(1-t)\theta}\mathbf a_0, \sin{(1-t)\theta}).$$

It is not hard to see $F$ is deformation retraction(even, it is **strong**!).

1. $\forall \mathbf a\in S^n, F(\mathbf a,0)=(\cos\theta\mathbf a_0,\sin\theta)=\mathbf a=\text{id}_{S^n}\mathbf a$.
2. $\forall \mathbf a\in S^n, F(\mathbf a,1)=(\mathbf a_0,0)\in S^{n-1}\times\{0\}$.
3. Since $\mathbf a\in S^{n-1}\times\{0\}$, then $\theta=0$, and it means $\mathbf a=(\mathbf a_0,0)$. So, $\forall\mathbf a\in S^{n-1}\times\{0\}, 0\le t\le1$, $F(\mathbf a,t)=(\mathbf a_0,0)=\mathbf a$.

Comment: What an excellent answer !

Answer (score 0):

Another way to approach this is to prove that if you remove from the suspension $$SX = (X\times I)/(X\times 0 \sqcup X\times 1)$$ the two distinguished points corresponding to $X\times 0$ and $X\times 1$, you get something that retracts onto $X$. This is clear, as you obtain something homeomorphic to $X\times (0,1)$. Since $S(S^p) = S^{p+1}$, this gives what you wanted.